# Python import from subfolder fails only when called from installed package

Tags: python, python-3.x, importerror

I'm having a problem after having recently switched from python2 to python3.8.

This is my file setup (abridged):

```
package/
       __init__.py
       main.py
       modules/
              __init__.py
              log.py
```

In python2 I used to import log.py into main.py with

```
import modules.log
```

When I do this in python3 and call main.py from the console with

```
python /path/to/package/main.py
```

everything works fine.

But then I create a python package from that and install it on my archlinux/raspberrypi and call the script via the console with

```
 /usr/bin/package
```

it tells me

```
$ package
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/package", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('package==3.1.1', 'console_scripts', 'package')()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 489, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2852, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2443, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2449, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/package/main.py", line 5, in <module>
    import modules.log
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'modules'
```

Any idea why it doesn't work? I suppose it looks in different places once installed as a package.

Thanks in advance

EDIT: I can successfully run the package when I change the imports to

```
from package.modules import log
```

But then it will only work if it is installed as a package. Running it from my IDE (where it is not installed as a package) will naturally result in the error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'package'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use relative imports for [intra-package references](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references), e.g. for `main.py` referencing `log.py` it would be:

```py
import .modules.log
```

There have been huge changes in `import` behavior between Python 2 and 3. Refer to [The Conservative Python 3 Porting Guide: Importing](https://portingguide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/imports.html)

For local development purposes there is a nice option to install package as a symlink

```sh
pip install -e ./ --user
```

In that case it will keep your installed package up-to-date with source, while you will be able to use this package as usual.

Comment: this has been the quickest solution to my problem and which didn't involve editing any files. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify what is root of your source files to packaging utitlity.
I expectiong you have standard setup.py with your package definition.

Look at package_dir option
https://python.readthedocs.io/en/stable/distutils/examples.html

(Alternatively you can change PYTHONPATH in you ide configuration and use package.modules)